# Polymer 1.0 iron-ajax and template not working

Tags: templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

I was trying to run a simple page that fetches data via iron-ajax and then renders it with a given template but had litarlly no success. Then I tried to run an example page from google and it's not working for me neither. Here's the example page I'm trying to run:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>iron-ajax</title>

    <script src="/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/iron-image/iron-image.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/paper-styles/classes/typography.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <style>
        iron-image {
            background-color: lightgray;
            margin: 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
               params='{"part":"snippet", "q":"polymer", "key": "AIzaSyAuecFZ9xJXbGDkQYWBmYrtzOGJD-iDIgI", "type": "video"}'
               handle-as="json"
               last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

    <h1>Video Feed</h1>
    <section class="flex layout horizontal wrap">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.items]]">
            <div>
                <h2><a href="[[url(item.id.videoId)]]" target="_blank">[[item.snippet.title]]</a></h2>
                <iron-image src="[[item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url]]" width="256" height="256" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
                <p>[[item.snippet.description]]</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    var app = document.querySelector('#app');
    app.url = function (videoId) {
        return 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My bower.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-polymer-app",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "authors": [
    "123"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "moduleType": [],
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#1.1.0",
    "flatiron-director": "Polymer/flatiron-director#~1.0.0",
    "sortable-table": "~0.11.1"
  }
}
```

I also tried import polymer.html with no change. Every import is working as I can see in a network tab in Chrome.
The actual endpoint is hit, I can see that in network tab of my chrome. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the folder structure for your project?

Comment: I was about to post my directory structure as I took a look on my page. And then I realized I was using Mustache for my page and Mustache destroyed my curly brackets.  Thanks a lot.